# SSH with the -F option returns me usage

Tags: ssh

I want to create a config file and tell ssh to deal with it. **I don't want to use ~/.ssh/config** because these are config files per project and not per user. So I'm trying to roll with:

```
ssh -F project_servers.ssh
```

And terminal returns ssh usage. This is the contents of the file I want SSH to play with:

```
Host preview
User xxxx
Port 52
HostName xxxx.com
```

Anybody knows what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You still need to request the named `Host` section on the command line:

```
ssh -F project_servers.ssh preview
```

Comment: i hope you'll never extinct! Thank you sir, that was the hack indeed!